# Form won't validate without ID main-contact form

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a kind of weird problem. I have a form which is a subscribe form for mail chimp. The form works perfectly if I don't have validation (When it says "Please fill this out" or "Please include an @ in the email")

It also works if I had an ID `id="main-contact-form"` however then, the mailchimp success / failure reply opens in a new tab. The problem is I don't want it to go to another tab, I want it to show up in the specially marked div. Which would work If I didn't have the main-contact-form ID but then I don't have the validation I want.

Here's the form:

```
        <form name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form"
              action="//leilamasson.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0178d0b7b81eec71fd9e2ee9b&amp;id=63fbfa0062"
              method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form main-contact-form"
              target="_blank">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="FNAME" class="form-control" required="required"
                       placeholder="Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="LNAME" class="form-control" required="required"
                       placeholder="Last Name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" required="required"
                       placeholder="Email Adress">

            </div>
            <div id="form-group">
                <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
                <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Subscribe</button>
            </div>

            <div style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;" aria-hidden="true"><input type="text"
                                                                                      name="b_0178d0b7b81eec71fd9e2ee9b_63fbfa0062"
                                                                                      tabindex="-1" value="">
            </div>
        </form>
```

and here's an example of the form I want without validation:

```
<form action="//leilamasson.us7.list-manage.com/subscribe/post?u=0178d0b7b81eec71fd9e2ee9b&amp;id=63fbfa0062"
      method="post" id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form" name="mc-embedded-subscribe-form">

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="EMAIL" class="form-control" required="required"
               placeholder="Email Adress">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" name="subscribe" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Subscribe</button>
    </div>
    <div id="form-group">
        <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
        <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
    </div>

</form>
```

Note: The bottom form doesn't have the ID main-contact-form which doesn't let it have validation, and the top form has the ID main-contact-form which forces it to open in a new tab.

The problem can be seen live at [leila.moussaieff.info](http://leila.moussaieff.info) under the social section.

Comment: So... where's the code doing the validation? Is it server side or client side?

Comment: You can't alter the mail chimp form and expect it to work especially changing the ID name.

Comment: @Mistergreen well it does work right now.

Comment: @NickBailey It just worked like that. No server side code. It just came with the template. I can't find out where the code is.

Comment: remove `target="_blank"`  if you don't want to go to new tab

Comment: Ok, I see, you don't have direct access to the server. Are you doing client side validation in JS

Comment: @NickBailey No, there is no server. Everything is client side hosted on github. github.com/manu354/trickle

Comment: @Sachin it's not that its opening in a new tab its that it changes websites

Comment: @manu you can't have a website without a server, by definition there is some computer somewhere that is returning the HTML, CSS and Javascript to the client. In the case of your form, there is a server somewhere that knows how to handle POST requests to the URI specified in the action.

Comment: @NickBailey thats not what I meant, the server is github. Everything is client side. Heres all the code: https://github.com/manu354/trickle

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a space in the id - this will effecively split up the portions and will cause issues:

```
...id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form main-contact-form"...
```

should be similar to (an underscore added):

```
...id="mc-embedded-subscribe-form_main-contact-form"...
```

Also you really should have labels for the inputs with for="xyz" with xyz being the id of the input. This allows screen readers to tie the label to a specific input.

Note that your div for the errors has an id of form group - when all others have a class of form group:

```
...<div id="form-group">
     <div class="response"...
```

should be

```
...<div class="form-group">
     <div class="response"...
```

Also as an aside  - rather than hiding a div all the way off screen with a text input in it - why not have a hidden input:

```
<input type="hidden" name="b_0178d0b7b81eec71fd9e2ee9b_63fbfa0062" value="" />
```

Comment: Thanks! They were all useful, but the main problem still remains.

Comment: do the form submission by AJAX which will allow you to fill the div with the content you want.

Comment: I have no idea how to do that. Unless theres a simple fix. I might just let it open up in the website.